# Excel-VBA Named range row sum

Tags: vba, excel, sum, named-ranges

I have the following code

```
 For i = 1 To DepRng.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To DepRng.Columns.Count
         DepRng.Cells(i, j) = Application.Sum(KidsRng.Row(i)) //Does not work
    Next j
 Next i
```

Although I know is wrong, i have no idea how to get it to store in `DepRng.Cells(i, j)` the total sum of the whole `KidsRng.Row[i]`  Any help?

Comment: Can you add in a definition of KidsRng ?

Comment: sorry i dont follow, what do you mean by adding a definition?

Comment: Seems that DepRng.Columns.Count should be 1 ... if not you are repeating the same value

Comment: tnx for your comment. Deleted my "answer" since it was just a clarification petition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorted, thanks all for ur help

```
   DepRng.Cells(i, j) = Application.Sum(KidsRng.Rows(i)) //just needed to add the "s" in rows
```

Comment: its for another row i just had it there for now, but j will be filled with other row ranges. Sorry for the confusion though, and thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

The following code works ok.

Perhaps you should compare it with yours:

```
Sub a()

Dim DepRng As Range
Dim kidsrng As Range
Set DepRng = Range("B1:B2")
Set kidsrng = Range("C1:F2")

 For i = 1 To DepRng.Rows.Count
      DepRng.Cells(i, 1) = Application.Sum(kidsrng.Rows(i))
 Next i

End Sub
```

Just fill the range C1:F2 with numbers and the totals per row will appear in B1:B2 upon execution of the macro.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better way than this, but this is my solution which depends on the internal Excel formula engine though, it might be sufficient enough for what you're doing...  It determines the full address of KidsRng.Row(i), and feeds it into a =SUM() formula string and evaluated by Application.Evaluate.

```
For i = 1 To DepRng.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To DepRng.Columns.Count

        DepRng.Cells(i, j).Value = Application.Evaluate("=SUM(" & KidsRng.Row(i).Address(True, True, xlA1, True) & ")")

    Next j
 Next i
```

updated it to work if kidsrng existed in a different sheet/book
updated to use Application.Evaluate